# Python3 does not compile source files

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation

I cannot compile with Python 3, i.e. the .pyc files are not generated.

For example:

```
python -m py_compile test.py
```

generates test.pyc

Hovewer,

```
python3 -m py_compile test.py
```

does not **generate** test.pyc

test.py

```
print("hello world")
```

Why?

Comment: Did you check the `__pycache__` directory? By default, `/foo/bar/baz.py` will be compilied into `/foo/bar/__pycache__/baz.cpython-36.pyc`. (The exact name varies depending on python version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3, you can find **.pyc** file in the `__pycache__` directory, beside your `test.py` script.

#### From terminal:

```
$ python3 -m py_compile test.py
$ ls __pycache__
 test.cpython-36.pyc
```

#### Inside python3

Use `py_compile` module:

```
>>> import py_compile
>>> py_compile.compile('test.py')
```

See:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/py_compile.html